# Make Ball rolling down function animation

Tags: python, mathematics

I am making an animation to explain gradient descent, and for it, I want to have an animation of a ball rolling down a 3d function graph. how do i this with blender and make it similar to this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IHZwWFHWa-w 7 minutes and 15 seconds into the video is the animation im talking about

Comment: I would use a follow path constraint: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SqOso5jgYa4

Comment: if you want the graph of an actual function, scripting is the way to go. He in the video does it with python scripts himself.